# Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain for Goole Plus login on web

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-signin

I am using public ip address example : mypublicdomain.com

I have not set any redirect url on developer console.

It works fine for when i do it on localhost. It is not working on public ip address.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Add `http://mypublicdomain.com` and `https://mypublicdomain.com` to your redirect uris AND allowed javascript origins - that should fix it.